# What is the difference between Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Cloud under LXC?

Tags: cloud, lxc

I want to set up Ubuntu LXC containers. Is there a practical difference between the `/usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-ubuntu` and `/usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-ubuntu-cloud`?

I only have a single physical server running 12.04.

Comment: Shouldn't have much difference. The cloud one should have even smaller footprint (less packages and services) I guess.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer? If so, please post here.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/293275/what-is-lxc-and-how-to-get-started/293302#293302

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu template - uses debootstrap to create the new container and hence downloads and installs .deb packages to create the initial chroot.

Ubuntu-Cloud template - downloads preinstalled cloud image and unpacks it.

Ubuntu template is closer to a standard ubuntu-server installation.
The cloud images have smaller footprint than ubuntu-server installtion and has hooks to launch it with cloud-init and juju.