# What is LXC and how to get started?

Tags: virtualization, lxc

I will appreciate if someone could introduce me to LXC and tell me how to get started with this technology? In which cases does it make sense to use, and in which should i stay away from it?

Comment: If you watch the movie **Inception** you have a good idea of lxc. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/ Trailer.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### _________________________________________________ L X C _________________________________________________________

```
                           Linux Containers ( Ubuntu )
```

> ### **Overview**
>
> Linux Containers (LXC) are lightweight virtualization technology and provide a free software virtualization system for computers running GNU/Linux, This is accomplished through kernel level isolation, It allows one to run multiple virtual units (containers) simultaneously on the same host.

A container is a way to isolate a group of processes from the others on a running Linux system. By making use of existing functionality like the Linux kernel's new resource management and resource isolation features (Cgroups and name spaces), these processes can have their own private view of the operating system with its own process ID (PID) space, file system structure and network interfaces.

Containers share the same kernel with anything else that is running on it, but can be constrained to only use a defined amount of resources such as CPU, memory or I/O. By combining containers with other features like the Btrfs file system , it will be possible to quickly set up multiple lightweight isolated Linux instances on a single host. Therefore containers are better compared to Solaris zones or BSD jails.

[image]

> ### Installation

**Making LXC easier**

One of the main focus for Ubuntu LTS was to make LXC dead easy to use, to achieve this.
Creating a basic container and starting it on Ubuntu

```
 sudo apt-get install lxc
 sudo lxc-create -t ubuntu -n my-container
 sudo lxc-start -n my-container
```

Log In

```
sudo lxc-console -n my-container -t 1
```

This will default to using the same version and architecture as your machine, additional option are obviously available (–help will list them). Login/Password are ubuntu/ubuntu.

[For Detail Host Configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/lxc.html)

---

> **For More About LXC**

[Debian](http://wiki.debian.org/LXC)

[Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/linux/technologies/oracle-linux-containers-1898044.html)

[sourceforge](https://linuxcontainers.org/)

---

## [LXC Web Panel](http://lxc-webpanel.github.io/install.html)

> For Newbie I would recommend to use LXC Webpanel, The good part is that if you make a container through cli mode, It will show up in LXC Web Panel

```
  sudo apt-get install lxc debootstrap bridge-utils -y
  sudo su
  wget https://lxc-webpanel.github.com/tools/install.sh -O - | bash
```

Open Web Browser and Connect

```
                       http://your_ip_address:5000/
                Login with user admin and password admin
```

### Overview

[image]

> Containers Overview

[image]

> LXC Network

[image]

> Container Settings

[image]

Resource Limitation

[image]

> User Modification ( Create, Delete Modify )

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had to install `sudo apt-get install debootstrap` before `sudo lxc-create -t ubuntu -n my-container` would work (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).

Comment: what are the features of btrfs that make the container provisioning faster?

Comment: You should use an unprivileged container instead for better security (using `-t download` instead of `-t ubuntu`): https://stgraber.org/2014/01/17/lxc-1-0-unprivileged-containers/

Answer (score 11):

## [LXC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC)

LXC which is an abbreviated way of saying **LinuX Containers** is an operating system-level virtualization method for running multiple isolated Linux systems which are called **containers** on a single control host. Since LXC provides operating system-level virtualization, it is not via a full blown virtual machine, but rather it provides it's own virtual environment that has its own process and network space.

LXC relies on the **Linux kernel cgroups** ([Control Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups)) which is developed as part of LXC which is a feature to limit, account and isolate resource usage (CPU, memory, disk I/O, etc.) of process groups. It also relies on other kinds of namespace-isolation functionality, which were developed and integrated into the mainline Linux kernel.

In Ubuntu you can find tools like [Juju](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/provider-configuration-local.html) that are used with LXC. You can even find several tutorials:

- [How do I configure juju for local usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65359/how-do-i-configure-juju-for-local-usage)
- [How do I run Juju on a local server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281530/running-juju-on-a-local-server?lq=1)
- [Can I use juju with LXC in a non-local configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195305/can-i-use-juju-with-lxc-in-a-non-local-configuration)

To use LXC and it's benefits I recommend reading the [Ubuntu Guide for Juju](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/getting-started.html)

**Official Site** -  https://linuxcontainers.org/

Mailing lists are hosted [here](https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/listinfo)

Answer (score 2):

I think a better question is what do you want to do with LXC?

I would start with the community documentation and ask specific questions about specific things you do not understand.

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/lxc.html

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LXC

LXC can be used to isolate services or other processes from the host although the isolation is not always perfect.

LXC is, IMO, in rapid development and it may help if you subscribe to the mailing list.

http://lxc.sourceforge.net/index.php/about/lxc-development/

Distrowatch also did a nice overview last week

http://distrowatch.com/weekly.php?issue=20130429#qa