# "Can not write log, openpty() failed (/dev/pts not mounted?)"

Tags: lxc

I used [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293275/what-is-lxc-and-how-to-get-started) to install LXC. The installation is success and creating the container complain give this message:

```
"Can not write log, openpty() failed (/dev/pts not mounted?)"
```

but in the end succeed, when I try to start the container gives to me this error message:

```
lxc-start: failed to create vethaPc2Ww-vethEbkHJT : Operation not supported
lxc-start: failed to create netdev
lxc-start: failed to create the network
lxc-start: failed to spawn 'mycon'
lxc-start: No such file or directory - failed to remove cgroup '/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset//lxc/mycon'
```

I used linaro Ubuntu 12.04 on Odroid-x2 board, and the container config the same as my host system as I used the command `sudo lxc-create -t ubuntu -n mycon` to create *mycon*

Comment: Did you restart the system? lxc gave me some problems until I restarted the syste.

Comment: I restart system many times, but nothing work

Comment: If you need you may destroy the environment and recreate it again, use `sudo lxc-destroy -n mycon` then repeat the process again.

Comment: can you show the container definition file?